# Regex to match strings that are all punctuation but not strings with punctuation containing other characters

Tags: regex, r

I have some messy text responses that I'm trying to cleanup a little. I'm using R and want to match responses that are all punctuation for removal.

Is there a regexp I can use to match these:

```
!@#$
.
**********
```

But not these:

```
Hello.
!asdf
**********1
```

I had previously tried

```
x[grepl("^[[:punct:]+]", x)]
```

which only matches punctuation at first character with another punctuation character

Comment: What have you tried? Please share the code you have come up with so far. [Should “Give me a regex that does X” questions be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/285739#285739)

Comment: x[grepl("^[[:punct:]+]", x)]

Comment: Perhaps:  
`x[grepl("^[[:punct:]+]$", x)]` . Leaving out the closing `$` means you get a hit on the third one that was not desired.

Comment: That should be always added to the question body, with explanation what goes wrong with it. Surely, it would not work at all since `+` should not be inside the character class (it is considered a literal plus there, not *one or more times*).

Comment: @42- that would match a line having single char (pinct)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Good catch. Should have been `x[grepl("^[[:punct:]]+$", x)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use negation..

```
x[!grepl("\\w", x)]
```

or

```
x[!grepl("[a-zA-Z]", x)]
```

Your regex `x[grepl("^[[:punct:]+]", x)]` should check for a punctuation exists at the start.

Comment: You could at least explain why his attempt failed. That is why we want OPs to provide their efforts.

Comment: Thanks yes negation gets what I need if I include digits as well.
        x[!grepl("[a-zA-Z0-9]", x)]

Comment: Actually that matches some non-standard characters as well

Comment: @AlistairW don't know what u mean.. But this should work for your current input.

Comment: It matched 

    Ò®Õù¶½
but that's OK

Comment: It's not polite to swear in comments <g>.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[^\\w\\n]+$
```

You can use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cZ0sD2/6

Comment: @vks You still go on avoiding spaces between a final stop and the next sentence. Please change your template. And explain why "you can use this".